# How to populate Constraintlayout as view in carousel apdapter in motionlayout android?

Tags: android, carousel, android-motionlayout

I'm trying to use carousel widget in motionlayout for making OnBoardActivity. I'm create three layout contain first, second and third layour. Then I create on_board_activity layout. This is my code:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_on_board_scene">

<include
    android:id="@+id/first"
    layout="@layout/first_intro"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/second"
    layout="@layout/second_intro"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/third"
    layout="@layout/third_intro"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Carousel
    android:id="@+id/carousel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:carousel_backwardTransition="@+id/backward"
    app:carousel_firstView="@+id/second"
    app:carousel_forwardTransition="@+id/forward"
    app:carousel_infinite="true"
    app:carousel_nextState="@+id/next"
    app:carousel_previousState="@+id/previous"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="first,second, third" />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

I create file activity_on_board_scene.xml, too. But I can't populate view in kotlin file. How can I do that? What do I need for program run ok?

```
  override fun populate(view: View, index: Int) {
            // need to implement this to populate the view at the given index
            if (view is ConstraintLayout){
               //how can I do that?
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Carousel allows you to animate using 3  ConstraintSets defined in a MotionScene
It does not use 3 layouts.

In general Carousel is a MotionLayout helper you
should have some working idea how MotionLayout works.

- Here is a [Carousel demo app](https://github.com/faob-dev/MotionLayoutCarousel)
- [An explanation of how a
  Carousel works](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/carousel)
- [Introduction Videos on MotionLayout parts](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc-bcyUTIFAr97ZtRkwM7S4y)